# Capturing a pattern multiple times

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to parse all links inside an html string looking like the following:

```
<a href="javascript:makePopup('match_stats_popup.php?matchID=185934701')">Match Stats</a>
<a href="javascript:makePopup('http://www.atpworldtour.com/Share/Match-Facts-Pop-Up.aspx?t=416&y=2014&r=5&p=D643')">Match Stats</a>
```

The expected output is an array of links:

```
['match_stats_popup.php?matchID=185934701',
'http://www.atpworldtour.com/Share/Match-Facts-Pop-Up.aspx?t=416&y=2014&r=5&p=D643']
```

I have created this function but it does not stop when reaching the ":

```
function parseMatchStatsLinks(html) {
    var regex = /href="javascript:makePopup\('(.*)'\)"/g;
    var match = [];
    var links = [];

    while (match = regex.exec(html)) {
        links.push(match[1]);
    }

    return links;
}
```

Comment: what is wrong in it and what is expected output?

Comment: I think it keeps grabbing everything once the makePopup(' has matched.

Comment: it works http://regex101.com/r/bL1cV0/12

Comment: Check with the content of this page http://www.tennisinsight.com/player_activity.php?advancedSurface%5B%5D=0&advancedLocation%5B%5D=0&advancedOpponent%5B%5D=0&advancedAttribute%5B%5D=0&advancedTour%5B%5D=0&advancedOdds=0&advanced=0&match_id=&player1=&player2=&player=&activity=21&min_activity=0&player_id=186&activity=18&odds=0

Answer (score 0):

I had to add `?` to make it non-greedy :

```
 href="javascript:makePopup\('(.*?)'\)"
```

Comment: I was posting same when I asked for expected output but since you have not mentioned clear examples and outputs. hence I doubt. Next time keep it clear for sooner help. :)